# Finding boundaries of a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> Use cylindrical coordinates to ﬁnd the volume of the solid that is inside the surface $r^2+z^2=20$ but not above the surface $z=r^2$.

**My attempt**:
$r^2\leq z\leq \sqrt{20-r^2}$ and the intersection of $r^2+z^2=20$ and $z=r^2$ is a circle $x^2+y^2=4$. Hence 
$G=\{(r,\theta,z):0 \le r \le 2,0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, r^2 \le z \le \sqrt{20-r^2}\}$ and 
$$Volume=\iiint_G dV=\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt{20-r^2}} rdzd\theta dr$$

---

But According to solution the volumne consists of two portions, one inside the cylinder $r=2$ and one outside the cylinder:
$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{20-r^2}}^{r^2} rdzdrd\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}\int_2^{\sqrt{20}}\int_{-\sqrt{20-r^2}}^{\sqrt{20-r^2}} rdzdrd\theta$$I couldn't visualize the volume. And how they got these limits$?$ Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your set up seems fine to me, there is some wrong in the official solution or in the problem statement.

Comment: @user the official solutions are correct, have a look at the graph I've provided

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah ok the volume "NOT ABOVE", I've misread this part and evaluated the "UP"! I fix accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture in the $rz$-plane that might help. [image]

As you can see, if one does the integral in the $z$ direction first, the integral must be split in two at the black line because we want the region below the paraboloid.

Comment: **the area not above the paraboloid** seems confusing to me. Because the enclosed volume is bounded by the sphere not the paraboloid.

Comment: @Dr.Antidode that is not true, the volume is enclosed by both as described by the problem.

Comment: Ah focusing your picture give me the answer. I should consider the whole volume under the paraboloid. Thanks @Ninad Munshi

Answer (score 1):

The intersection is between a sphere and a paraboloid and we can evaluate the integral as a difference between the volume of the sphere and your set up for the part above the paraboloid that is

$$V=\frac43 \pi (\sqrt {20})^3-\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{2}rdr\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt {20-r^2}} dz$$

Comment: I wouldn't recommend symmetry approaches for triple integral problems. This does work in the case the integrand shares the same symmetry, but it would be a fair question to ask in a multivariable class to set up the integral for an arbitrary integrand $f(x,y,z)$ where this approach does not work.

Comment: @NinadMunshi In this case symmetry holds and it seems really the best approach to me.

Comment: This is simply my opinion after teaching multivariable for many years. It's kind of like using L'Hopital in a calculus one class when the instructor clearly wanted students to not use it, for example limits that look like $e$ or $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. The point is not to get the answer, but to learn how to set up the problems in specific ways, in this case cylindrical coordinates integrals. And this symmetry falls into the same category of learning traps.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I respect your opinion based on direct experience but for my experience I know that in other classes these kind of approach by symmetry are indicated as good solutions.More over here it seems to me that symmetry is not the key point, we are just avoiding one integarl using the well known formula for the volume of the sphere. it doesn't seem so bad to me.

Comment: Agreed, but this is not other classes like Electromagnetism, this is multivariable calculus where the educational goal is to learn how to set up integrals. The symmetry is nice to *verify* answers in simple cases, and I have had students do this on multipart homeworks, but this way of thought leaves students high and dry for more complicated scenarios, and I would not indicate this as a good solution for that goal. It is precisely because the integrand doesn't matter that I feel it is dangerous to use it explicitly.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Nice can hear these suggestions from you. Thanks a lot! Bye